# How does one unpack a file using zsh?

Tags: java, zsh

I am a RHEL user, and have to use Zsh for my work.

I am trying to unpack the rt.pack file in order to correct an incorrect java installation.

The command
`/usr/bin/unpack200 rt.pack rt.jar`

does not seem to be present in Zsh.

Can someone please tell me what the equivalent command in Zsh might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked finally: A clean installation of the rpm that had the jdk in it.

`rpm -Uvh <name of jdk>.rpm`

This extracted the appropriate files and placed them in the right paths.

Answer (score 0):

I don't own a RHEL laptop anymore, but what you need to do is likely just install Java (using the the RHEL package manager).

Otherwise just do a local JDK install and use it from there.

PS; you can always try `locate unpack200` to see if it is anywhere in your system or not.